# What is the proper locale code for Android for Simplified Chinese and Portugese-Brazil?

Tags: android, locale

In my app users have the ability to switch their app locale to one of the other app supported languages. I'm having issues getting Portuguese-Brazil and Simplified Chinese to work.  All other translations work properly when the user changes the locale settings.

These translations work properly if the device locale is pt-rBR or zh-rCN so the only thing that could be wrong is the locale code I use.  However, anything I've tried fails.  Anybody know the proper Android locale codes for these so users can properly switch if they desire?

Comment: The framework uses `-pt-rBR` and `-zh-rCN`, so those would appear to be correct values: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res

Comment: Those are the correct values for the strings.xml folders but for some reason they don't work when it comes to forcing the locale to change.  That's why this is so puzzling right now.  All other translations (ar, de, fr, ru, ja, and others) work just fine.  I know I could drop the strings.xml into a base directory like values-zh or values-pt and get it to work but that isn't the correct way to do it since zh is normally traditional Chinese.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not realize that you were trying to force the locale to change within your app.

Comment: @Jason I'm struggling with similar problem, I want to give both Chinese simplified and traditional support. Please share if you have found the solution

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
new Locale("pt","BR");
```

instead of

```
new Locale("pt_BR");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use following code its working for me for traditional and simplified chinese.

```
if(selectedLanguage.equals("zh_CN"))
    locale = Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE;
else if(selectedLanguage.equals("zh_TW"))
    locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE;
else
    locale = new Locale(selectedLanguage);

Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
baseContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, baseContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```